# Logo doesn't display using Django admin_interface

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, django-urls

I have django-admin-interface installed in my django app. The problem is that when I try to upload a logo it says that all is okay but the logo doesn't show.

Logo uploaded correctly but not showing
[image: 1]

I want to change the default Django logo.

[image: 2]

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new template and extends the 'admin' template like below to override the default admin template.

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">MY_LOGO_OR_TEXT</a></h1>
{% endblock %}
```

In the code above, change the MY_LOGO_OR_TEXT section with your html logo or just text to be shown on the admin panel like you wanted.

[ADMIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX0ES.jpg)

Comment: Well i tried that but my colors from django_interface were lost now my colors are default wich is blue and my client want both the logo and the colors.